# Apt-get always triggers tomcat's "setting up"

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, tomcat8

I needed to jump some hoops in order to install a specific version of tomcat, and thereby executed several guides' commands. Now, every time I use any apt-get or dpkg command, tomcat starts setting up and fails the whole install process.

Examples:

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up tomcat8 (8.0.32-1ubuntu1.4) ...
Job for tomcat8.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status tomcat8.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript tomcat8, action "start" failed.
● tomcat8.service - LSB: Start Tomcat.
   <snip>
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tomcat8

$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-image-4.4.0-97-generic linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-97-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-98-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 36 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up tomcat8 (8.0.32-1ubuntu1.4) ...
<snip>
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tomcat8
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
W: Operation was interrupted before it could finish
```

Anything that would normally fix my packages keeps triggering this. Does anyone know where this is caused and how to fix it?

Thank you in advance,

CX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed my own problem. I first rebooted into recovery mode, subsequently I chose the 'fix packages' option. It did error, and resuming got me into an infinite boot loop, but it still fixed enough so that I can use the package manager properly.